# A function similar to build-in map but support numpy broadcast

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to write a function `amap` which is similar to build-in `map` but support numpy broadcast and output array. It would work like this:

```
>>> amap(lambda x:x**2, 1)
array(1)
>>> amap(lambda x:x**2, [1, 2])
array([1, 4])
>>> amap(lambda x,y:y**2+x**2, 1, [1, 2])
array([2, 5])
>>> amap(lambda x,y:y**2+x**2, [1, 2], [[1], [2]])
array([[2, 5], [5, 8]])
```

The function passed-in operates on scalar.

I've written one implementation.

```
def amap(func, *args):
    '''array version of build-in map
    amap(function, scalar/sequence[, ...]) -> array
    '''
    args = np.broadcast(None, *args)
    res = [func(*arg[1:]) for arg in args]
    res = np.asarray(res).reshape(args.shape)
    return res
```

It works but it is somehow ugly and not very efficient.
 Do you have any good ideas to do this? Especially something more numpy-stylish?

Comment: Does the `lambda` (function) operate on whole arrays, or just scalars?

Comment: What kind of efficiency are you expecting?  Iterative calls with scalars, or array operations?

Comment: @hpaulj the function operates on just scalars, usually it's a complex function and hard to operate an array. I thought broadcasting with an extra `None` and making slice `arg[1:]` to drop `None` is less efficient.

Comment: When does that extra play with `None` help?  I assume it's there because of some edge case.  Assuming the real life arrays have hundreds elements, fiddling with dimensions like this is a minor time consumer.  What will take time is calling your function for many sets of values.

Comment: `np.frompyfunc` is another broadcasting tool.  `np.vectorize` uses it, but provides an different API.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I add `None` for the case only one list/scalar past in, `np.broadcast` require at least two objects. I agree, it's the function cost most. If the function itself does not support array computation, no matter how to orgnize the codes the time used should be always similar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) directly?

```
>>> numpy.vectorize(lambda x:x**2)(1)
array(1)
>>> numpy.vectorize(lambda x:x**2)([1,2])
array([1, 4])
>>> numpy.vectorize(lambda x, y: y**2 + x**2)(1, [1,2])
array([2, 5])
>>> numpy.vectorize(lambda x, y: y**2 + x**2)([1,2], [[1], [2]])
array([[2, 5],
       [5, 8]])
```

Comment: `vectorize` is not efficient, and internally it is rather ugly (i.e. long).